# Custom modal screen in TinyMCE 4 plugin in inline mode

Tags: plugins, tinymce, tinymce-4, bootstrap-modal

I am developing a custom plugin for the new TinyMCE 4. This plugin utilizes a modal screen. Because I want to use a modal screen/JS service I already developed I chose **not to use TinyMce's Window manager**.

The problem is that TinyMCE looses its focus as soon as I open my open modal screen. I want TinyMce to keep the toolbars opened, because otherwise I cannot interact with the editor. TinyMCe closes because it receives a blur event (and most likely because it does not know about any opened windows).

An minified problem showing the problem can be found in the following Fiddle. The problem occurs as soon as the *Example* button is clicked.
http://fiddle.tinymce.com/pudaab/1

The shortened code is attached below:

```
tinymce.PluginManager.add('example', function(editor, url) {
    // Add a button that opens a window
    editor.addButton('example', {
        text: 'My button',
        icon: false,
        onclick: function() {
            var selection = editor.selection,
                dom = editor.dom,
                selectedElm,
                anchorElm;

            // Focus the editor since selection is lost on WebKit in inline mode
            editor.focus();

           // Open a modal screen using bootstrap
            $('#elem').modal();

            // Note: As soon as modal opens TinyMce receives a blur event and disables the toolbar
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: hmm, you mean you are not able to use the popup?

Comment: The problem is that TinyMce loses focus. Thus it hides the toolbar. Because TinyMce has no focus anymore I am no longer able to perform actions on the editor. For example, I can no longer replace the selected text by something else.

Comment: couldn't you just refocus the editor right after the popup button is clicked and then do whatever you want with the editor?

Comment: That way you lose the position of the cursor, selection, etc.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I finally managed to solve it myself. The trick is to call `editor.nodeChanged()` before calling the modal screen. Then when you close your modal screen you call `editor.focus()`.

Thanks for the help though!

Comment: well, that's what i suggested

Comment: I already used `editor.focus()` in my code. The important part is using `editor.nodeChanged()`. That saves your current selection, etc. Did you hint on that solution in your reply? If so I mesread your post.

Comment: Just so you know, this approach does not seem to be working in the latest TinyMCE (`v.4.1.10` at the time of this comment). However there is an easy fix: add an `mce-in` class to your custom modal dialog.